# Pandas not reading first column from xlsx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working through one excel file where it contains multiple (36) sheets by month_year (Sep 18 - Oct 15) reading all of them using a dictionary

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = 'project_dropColumnICSv2.xlsx'
df = pd.ExcelFile(fileName)

sheetNames = df.sheet_names
vars_dict = {}

for sheetName in sheetNames:
    vars_dict["the_{0}".format(sheetName)] = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=sheetName, index_col=False)

mykeys = []

for key, value in vars_dict.items():
    mykeys.append(key)
```

I need to set their 14 column names all at once but I'm getting ValueError: Length mismatch

Here, we can see some sheets only contain 13 columns

```
for mykey in mykeys:
    print("'{}' contains {} columns".format((mykey), len(vars_dict.get(mykey).columns)))

'the_Sep 18' contains 14 columns
'the_Aug 18' contains 14 columns
'the_Jul 18' contains 14 columns
'the_Jun 18' contains 14 columns
'the_May 18' contains 14 columns
'the_April 18' contains 14 columns
'the_March 18' contains 14 columns
'the_February 18' contains 13 columns
'the_January 18' contains 14 columns
'the_December 17' contains 13 columns
'the_November 17' contains 13 columns
'the_October 17' contains 13 columns
'the_September 17' contains 13 columns
'the_August 17' contains 14 columns
'the_July 17' contains 14 columns
'the_June 17' contains 14 columns
'the_May 17' contains 14 columns
'the_April 17' contains 14 columns
'the_MARCH 17' contains 14 columns
'the_February17' contains 14 columns
'the_January17' contains 14 columns
'the_December16' contains 14 columns
'the_November16' contains 14 columns
'the_October 16' contains 14 columns
'the_September' contains 14 columns
'the_August' contains 15 columns
'the_July' contains 14 columns
'the_June' contains 14 columns
'the_May' contains 14 columns
'the_April' contains 14 columns
'the_March' contains 13 columns
'the_February' contains 13 columns
'the_January' contains 13 columns
'the_December' contains 13 columns
'the_November' contains 14 columns
'the_October' contains 13 columns
```

I tried just adding another column

```
for mykey in mykeys:
    if len(vars_dict.get(mykey).columns) == 13:
        vars_dict.get(mykey)['Another Column'] = 'Nan'
```

change the column names using a for loop, but got a result where first column has a wrong field, in short, misaligned.

Assuming a have an array of my column names, how can I make this work?

```
for mykey in mykeys:
    vars_dict.get(mykey).columns = column
```

P.S. there is one sheet that contain 15 columns, solved by simply dropping the last

Comment: So problem is why in your file is not read first column? Very hard to find problem without your real data (or data sample with same structure, values should be dummy data, if real are confidental). So is possible share your file - by gdocs, dropbox, similar?

Comment: The problem is in some of the sheets. First column ‘Date’ is not read while others have it as the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need parameter `sheet_name=None` for convert all sheets to `OrderedDict of DataFrames` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
fileName = 'project_dropColumnICSv2.xlsx'
dfs = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=None)
```

Then use dictionary comprehension for check number of columns and set new by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and create new dictionary:

```
dfs = {k: v.assign(New = np.nan) if len(v.columns) == 13 else v for k, v in dfs.items()}
```

Also if need change keys:

```
dfs = {f'the_{}'.format(k): v.assign(New = np.nan) 
       if len(v.columns) == 13 
       else v for k, v in dfs.items()}
```

Then select each DataFrame by key:

```
print (dfs['Sep 18'])
```